# Calendar highlights dates...how to change color?

Tags: asp.net, calendar

```
<asp:Calendar ID="calendarToDisplayWorkSiteDates" runat="server">
```

Bind to a list in code behind - which highlights all the dates in the list.(On screen)

When a user clicks on a date the page re-freshes but the date that the user has just selected changes to the same color 'silver' as dates which are highlighted (through the list).

Is there anyway to change the color so the user can tell which date they have clicked on and which dates are highlighted through the list.

Thank you

TRIED:
BackColor="Red"  but doesnt work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `DayRender` event ([Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar.dayrender%28v=vs.80%29.aspx))

```
protected void cal_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Day.IsToday)
    e.Cell.BackColor = Color.Red;
  else if (e.Day.IsWeekend)
    e.Cell.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
  else if (e.Day.IsSelected)
    e.Cell.BackColor = Color.Orange;
  // else if day exists in your list
  // Color the cell in different color
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code to change the color of the selected date.

```
 calendarToDisplayWorkSiteDates.SelectedDayStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
```

Comment: thanks for the reply milton..where as before the background color to all the dates was silver, it is now green, including the date the user has selected...Is there no way to seperate the two?
 foreach (DateTime d in DiaryEntry.Select(de => de.Date))
        {
            calendarToDisplayWorkSiteDates.SelectedDates.Add(d);
            calendarToDisplayWorkSiteDates.SelectedDayStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
        }